# WSUS Configuration Fails on SCCM 2012 SP1 on Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, sccm-2012

I've installed SCCM 2012 SP1 on Server 2012.  CU10 on SQL 2008 R2 SP2 and CU4 on SCCM.  I go through the process of installing the WSUS role which appears to complete successfully but when I attempt to do the post installation configuration it fails.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled with no success and have looked at the many suggestions on how to fix this that are available online but can't get any of the suggestions to resolve the issue.  I have checked the IIS console looking for this but don't see the WSUS IIS Website.  Is this part of the configuration that does not happen?  When I check the Supsetup.log file it tells me the WSUS installation was successful.  Attempting to run the post install configuration through Server Manager fails as well.  I have attempted to install and configure using PowerShell with the same results.  Any ideas or suggestions?

The output log file when I try to run the post-install configuration shows this:

2014-02-14 09:08:51  Got binary SID
 2014-02-14 09:08:51  Setting content location...
 2014-02-14 09:08:51  Fetching ContentDir from registry store
 2014-02-14 09:08:51  Value is D:\WSUS
 2014-02-14 09:08:51  Swtching DB to multi-user mode......
 2014-02-14 09:08:51  Finished setting multi-user mode
 2014-02-14 09:08:51  Writing DB settings to registry...
 2014-02-14 09:08:51  Marking PostInstall done for UpdateServices-Database in the registry...
 2014-02-14 09:08:51  Starting service W3SVC
 2014-02-14 09:08:52  Configuring IIS...
 2014-02-14 09:08:52  Start: ConfigureWebsite
 2014-02-14 09:08:52  Configuring website on port 8530
 2014-02-14 09:09:02  System.ArgumentException: Cannot find system setting. Please check setting name.
 Parameter name: IISTargetWebSiteIndex
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.MachineSettingRedirector.GetValue(String valueName)
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.IisConfiguration.Load()
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.IisConfiguration.UpdateRegistry()
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UseCustomWebSite.InstallAndConfigure(IisConfiguration& iisConfiguration, Int32 newPortNumber)
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.ConfigureWebsite(Int32 portNumber)
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.Run()
    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.Execute(String[] arguments)

I am thoroughly stumped on what to do to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SCCM 2012 is a nightmare to install.  Forget about it, and setup SCCM 2012 R2 instead.

Comment: I haven't really seen that.  I've done more than a few of these without issue.  This is the first time I've encountered this "problem".